# use double for loop to access element in datafram in r

Tags: r, loops

I want to use double `for` to access an element and populate it inside of a list. two `for` loop including first based on column `ID` and second based on column `sem` then use `if` to check if course is `"math"` 
let's say:

```
df:
ID  sem  course
10  1    "math"
10  1    "phys"
10  1    "other"
10  2    "math"
10  2    "phys2"
10  2    "chem"
11  1    "other"
11  2    "math"
```

here is sodu code

```
mylist=list(NA)
for in each ID {
   for j in each sem{
      check the element course=='math'{
          insert it into mylist (or do some other stuffs here)
 }}}
```

my purpose is to use loops to check each element of column. 
result:

```
mylist
"math","math", "math"
```

Comment: like this: `lapply(list(df$course), function(x) x[x =='math'])`

Comment: What exactly is `some other stuff` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about without any loop

```
rep("math",sum(df$course == "math"))
# returns
[1] "math" "math" "math"
```

with

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L), 
sem = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2), course = c("math", "phys", 
"other", "math", "phys2", "chem", "other", "math")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```